# Phase diagram and criterion for linear nullclines

Tags: generalized-eigenvector

I have two equations $\frac{dq}{dt}$= $Rq + K - 1$ and $\frac{dK}{dt}$=$ Nq + N$. Here, N and R are just constants so I was ignoring them and just assigning a certain arbitrary value. Solving nullclines for this gives me $q = (1-K)/r$ and $q=-1$. So both of them are going to intersect at the fourth quadrant.

My trouble right now is sketching the phase portrait for this. Are the two eigenvectors supposed to be the same as the two nullclines? I always thought eigenvectors are nullclines were more or less different ideas but is the point of intersection of the two nullcines the stable equilibrium path for this solution?

Comment: You can write your system as $$\begin{pmatrix}q\\ K\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}R&1\\ N&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}q\\ K\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ N\end{pmatrix}$$ This system isn't homogeneous. Employing the eigenvector method would require that you enforce a substitution like $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}q+1\\ K-R-1\end{pmatrix}$$ This will transform your system into one thats homogeneous, *then* you can apply classic eigenvector method.

Comment: so, will one of my eigenvectors be the nullcline itself? I think not but can that ever happen?

Comment: One of your eigenvectors? Of what matrix? Generally speaking, if you have a homogeneous system $x'=Ax$ a nullcline need not be the span of some eigenvector of $A$, but it could be. Consider $x'=x,y'=y-x$.